# Live program output monitoring tool

Tags: command-line, monitoring

I would like to know if there is a tool that would enable you to watch how the program output changes live. Something like `tail -f` but instead of monitoring the file changes, it would repeatedly call some executable and display it live.

For example, if the tool is caled `foobar` and I would call `foobar 'ps -Al'`, it would behave kind of like `top` - displaying the output in real time.

Comment: Do you want to watch a file for changes and run a command, or watch the commands output for changes and run it at a set interval?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `watch`. From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch):

> **Name**
>
> `watch` - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> watch [-dhvt] [-n <seconds>] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=<seconds>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> `watch` runs command repeatedly, displaying its output (the first screenfull). This allows you to watch the program output change over time. By default, the program is run every 2 seconds; use `-n` or `--interval` to specify a different interval.
>
> The `-d` or `--differences` flag will highlight the differences between successive updates. The `--cumulative` option makes highlighting "sticky", presenting a running display of all positions that have ever changed. [...]
>
> `watch` will run until interrupted.

Note that "realtime" would have to be approximated by "once a second" (for example) here...